# RollupJS and TSC - how to fail build if circular dependency is detected

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I have a React component library build, using RollupJS (2.7) and TypeScript (3.9.10), which is helpfully reporting circular dependencies:

```sh
>> yarn build
(!) Circular dependency
src/index.ts -> src/components/index.ts -> src/components/Button/index.ts -> src/components/Button/Button.tsx -> src/index.ts
```

The build still completes however:

```sh
created ./dist/index.esm.js, ./dist/index.js in 4.3s
```

I looked through the documentation for [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) and [rollup.config.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files) but didn't see any configuration changes I could make relating to circular dependencies.

Is there a way (via the tooling, i.e., tsconfig, rollup.config) that we can have the **build fail if a circular dependency is detected**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/408#issuecomment-168326577) I was made aware of the `onwarn` API.

I'm not seeing official Rollup doc for `onwarn`, but I was able to solve my problem by adding this to the top level of my `rollup.config.js`:

```js
onwarn: (message) => {
  // fail build if circular dependencies are found
  if (message.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY') {
    console.error(message);
    process.exit(-1);
  }
},
```